# Licensing: upgrading microsoft visual studio 2008 to 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, licensing

I am a freelancer. I personally bought years ago a physical version of VS2008 pro at a local shop for doing side contracts. While, change happens.

I move, I change laptops, I change employers, I got access to MSDN, I lost access to MSDN, I installed VS2010 pro, life go on.

So now, I own this laptop where VS2008 pro have never been installed. VS2010 pro is installed with a serial number from my employer X that have access to MSDN. I will change to employer Y. So I will remove the license key. Employer Y do not allow remote work and to not lend any laptop.

After working with VS2010 pro for a few years, I will like to upgrade my personal serial number from VS2008 pro to VS2013 pro.

Before spending the money and time installing, uninstalling, resolving conflict issue, etc. I would like to confirm that my serial number and version is OK for the upgrade from VS2008 pro to VS2013 pro.

Does someone bought an upgrade of VS2013? If yes, when do you need to use your old key? Like is it during the installation of VS2013? Do I need VS2008 installed? does the installation even care about your VS2008 key or is it only when Microsoft audit us?

Thank you!
Sebastien

Comment: I chatted with two Microsoft reps and their answers were contradictory. This is not the first time that me of my colleague contact microsoft and got confusion results. So I take this as I cannot rely on them.

Comment: I also tried to register my VS2008 pro key in my live account but I did not find any link to do this. Except I found a several 404 error page related to VS2008.

Comment: You might want to contact MS directly and get their advice.  Asking here may very well get you an incorrect answer that could land you in a pot of boiling water so to speak in the long run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/369450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I spoke to another Microsoft Rep.

Conclusion, I have to buy a new version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only Visual Studio 2012 can be upgrade.

Reference: http://www.microway.com.au/microsoft/visual-studio-upgrade.php